# Why is my converted column marked by JpaAttributeTypeInspection with the error message "'Basic' attribute type should not be a map"?

Tags: json, hibernate, intellij-idea, jpa

I was trying to store some JSON as a string in a column via JPA and Spring and was following a [baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object). My code like this:

```java
    @Column
    @Convert(converter = MyEntityExtentionConverter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> myEntityExtention;
```

`MyEntityExtentionConverter` is an implementation of `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String>` that converts the string back and forth using the Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

According to mentioned tutorial this should have been it, however now I get an Error that

> 'Basic' attribute type should not be a map

Theoretically I could disable it by adding `@SuppressWarnings("JpaAttributeTypeInspection")` to the annotations, but that feels like ignoring rather than solving the error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the application itself work? Look like the `Column` can not be of type `Map` - Does it help if you remove `Column` annotation?

Comment: Removing the ```Column``` does not change the situation or the error.

Whether or not the Application works I'm not yet clear about, since this is part of a big change and I need to finish up a few other parts first to see if it would run.

Comment: same here, anyone has suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

**You have to annotate prop "myEntityExtention" with @Type** but **is not possible to add both @Type and @Convert..**

as you can see [in this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-types-library) **you have to define the json type** on the top of your entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table_name")
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
public class CustomEntity {
```

then add **@Type** annotation instead **@Convert**:

```
@Type( type = "json" )
private Map<String, Object> myEntityExtention;
```

**be sure to add all the right dependencies/versions.**

I.E. i'm using hibernate 5.4 so my dependencies are:

```
<!-- Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final (inherited from spring-boot 2.3.4)-->
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>        
 </parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <!--for hibernate >= 5.2-->
            <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 7):

Look like this is an issue from IntelliJ IDEA:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270687

We can use workaround by this way:
Using the `@SuppressWarnings("JpaAttributeTypeInspection")` annotation removes the warning.

Answer (score 0):

That field is not meant to be persisted. Remove the @Column annotation and use @Transient.
You are supposed to persist it as a JSON which will be done in the customerAttributeJSON, when reading from the database the customerAttributes will be populated and you can use it with DTOs.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")
public class Customer {
 
    @Id
    private int id;
 
    private String firstName;
 
    private String lastName;
 
    private String customerAttributeJSON;
 
    @Transient
    @Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> customerAttributes;
}
```